# C# socket array

Tags: c#, arrays, sockets, networking

I would like to create an array of sockets in C#.  This is how I have 1 socket:

```
static Socket my_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

But, whatever I try it won't let me make an array.

How do I do it?

Comment: Read about arrays http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: `whatever I try it won't let me make an array.` for example?

Comment: I tried 

static Socket[] my_socket = new Socket[10](AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

and

static Socket[] my_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)[10];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an array, you could use a List, which is basiclly an array, but improved and offers more flexibility such as adding/removing and searching using Linq. Here's an example how you would declare the list and add three sockets to it:

```
List<Socket> MySocketList = new List<Socket>();

Socket Socket1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
Socket Socket2 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
Socket Socket3 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

MySocketList.Add(Socket1);
MySocketList.Add(Socket2);
MySocketList.Add(Socket3);

// MySocketList[0] is 'Socket1'
```

**Edit: After the OP's comment:**

```
List<Socket> MySocketList = new List<Socket>();

for(int i = 0; i < 1015; i++)
{   
    Socket NewSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    MySocketList.Add(NewSocket);
}

// MySocketList now contains 1015 sockets, you can loop trough them, and open a connection:

foreach(Socket CurrentSocket in MySocketList)
{
    CurrentSocket.Connect(...);
}
```

Comment: Well actually I will need around 1000-1050 sockets, to debug an Agentserver and thats why I wanted to make an array, it would save a lot of typing.

Answer (score 1):

Once you create your array (the container), you need to fill it with sockets. If you have a lot of values, the best way is with a classic `for` loop :

```
// Declaration
Socket[] sockets = new Socket[numberOfSocketsYouNeed];
// Initalization
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSocketsYouNeed; i++)
{
    sockets[i] = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
}
```

You can also merge the two steps with LINQ, but you'll get a small performance hit for larger arrays.

```
Scoket[] sockets = Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfSocketsYouNeed)
                     .Select(_ => new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
                     .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create your array first and then populate your array with socket objects.

```
Socket[] my_sockets = new Socket[10];

foreach(Socket a_socket in my_sockets)
{
     a_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
}
```